# Caching similar to Varnish on Windows Server

Tags: varnish, cache

I'm looking for a caching for IIS similar to the Varnish.. But as Varnish is not recommended on Windows, I would like to have suggestions as what are the other alternatives that can be used for performance optimization of ASP.net web applications & websites that are similar & powerful as Varnish.

Comment: Aside from the fact that it would be horribly unsupported, why not use Varnish? ([Their Wiki seems to imply that you can run it under Cygwin](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/Installation))

Comment: You can use memcached. http://memcached.org/

Comment: you can use docker :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need that when IIS - actually Windows - has an output cache already included in the kernel (http.sys can do caching)? Is there a real need, or are you unaware of IIS and ASP.NET's output cache functionality?

The documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.100).aspx

is a good start. You can cache, invalidate by parameter, do partial caching in a page (i.e. only those parts that do not change). It is all there out of the box.

I've never seen a need for external additional caching, but maybe there IS something special that your need that ASP.NET and IIS does not already do.

Comment: I think this is written in a brusque way that is neither respectful to the OP, nor appropriate for Stack Exchange's constructive Q&A style. I ain't gonna downvote you, though, because it does contain useful info.

Comment: @TomTom - We ended up using object and output cache provided by dot net, and we're happy using that.

Comment: Gratulations to that. I found it amazing in most circumstances, too. Add to that a distributed CDN (CloudFlare) and you have the tools to take a LOT of load off your server.

Comment: I'd say that APP pool recycling is the primary reason why you may consider an out of process caching.